# Evaluated variable and successfully evaluated package in VS-2017 SSIS does not work when executed in ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, ssms

In VS-2017 I have written a variable with the datatype "string". This variable uses another variable in order to determine from what moment in time data should extracted from a database.

The issue at hand is that the expression is evaluated in VS successfully, the ssis package can be executed successfully and the query itself can be executed in ssms. When the package is deployed to ssms and executed throughout the Integration Service Catalog the package doesn't work. The package fails at the first 'or' statement

the message I get from the execution reports says:

> "incorrect syntax near the statement 'or'".

The evaluated value (a correct sql query) works fine when executed in ssms.
I tried to place an empty string before or after the `'or'` statement, didn't solve the issue.
I tried to replace the `'or'` statement with `'and'`, didn't work.
Executed without the `'where'` statement the packages works as expected.
In another package I was unable to duplicate the error

```
"  select * from src where id >= "+ @[User::MaxIdStr] +" or id >= "+  @[User::MaxIdStr]
```

The piece of code where the bug seems to be:

```
where
[DateUpdated (CCUPMJ)] >= "+ @[User::Max_Upmj_Start]  +" 
or F0911.[DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)] >= "  +  @[User::Max_Upmj_Start]+"
or F560911T.[DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)] >= "+ @[User::Max_Upmj_Start]
```

In VS it is evaluated as:

```
[DateUpdated (CCUPMJ)] >= 119121 

or F0911.[DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)] >= 119121

or F560911T.[DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)] >= 119121
```

(119121 is the default value of the variable)

The expected result should be an successfully executed package, the actual result is an failed execution.

If someone knows how to solve this I would be very graceful!

Comment: You've lost me. The first snipped of code you filter against the id column. In the second and third, you filter against different DateUpdated columns. When you package begins execution, how does it identify the correct MaxIdStr and/or Max_Upmj_Start values

Comment: not enough information here to help you.   How is the variable populated?   You mention it uses "another variable".   What is that variable, how does it use it, and how is the other variable populated?   In short, if you don't show us enough of the package that we can create our own package that reproduces the issue, we can't possibly help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]` being assigned an empty string or null during package execution?  Using an empty string variable, I was able to reproduce the same "incorrect syntax near the statement 'or'" error you received.  Since `119121` is the default value you can use the SSIS `IF` statement to check the length of the variable, and substitute `119121` when there isn't a value.  The `LEN` function checks for this below, and uses the default value when the length of `@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]` is less than 1.  For clarification, the `IF` syntax is displayed right above the example expression for this variable.  Since this is nested each `IF` statement is wrapped in parenthesis.  I'm assuming you omitted the beginning of the variable with a full `SELECT` statement, so this example just uses a dummy SELECT * FROM ... as a placeholder.  Even though it holds a number, from your expression it seems that `@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]` is a string variable and the example below follows this assumption.  Be aware that SSIS variables do not hold null, and for a string variable an empty string will be substituted for this, so using the `REPLACENULL` function won't be helpful here.

**IF Syntax:**

```
Expression ? True Condition : False Condition
```

**Variable Expression:**

```
"SELECT * FROM ... WHERE
[DateUpdated (CCUPMJ)] >= " + 
(LEN(@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]) < 1 ? "119121" : @[User::Max_Upmj_Start]) 
+ "OR F0911.[DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)] >=  " + 
(LEN(@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]) < 1 ? "119121" : @[User::Max_Upmj_Start])+ "
OR F560911T.[DateUpdated (GLUPMJ)]  >=  " + 
(LEN(@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]) < 1 ? "119121" : @[User::Max_Upmj_Start])
```

Comment: I think it is easier to use `REPLACENULL()` function.

Comment: @Hadi `REPLACENULL` would be more concise, although since a variable is used here it won't be null, but an empty string instead, and the second argument of `REPLACENULL` won't be used.  Just to double-check I tried replacing the `LEN` functions with `REPLACENULL` but this didn't return the replacement condition when the string variable had no value assigned.

Comment: You're right after testing `REPLACENULL()`, it didn't replace the value since it contains an empty string. I rolled back my edit.

Comment: No problem, thanks for updating the edit on the post.

Comment: ```@[User::Max_Upmj_Start]``` was indeed assigned with a null during execution. ```Select *``` was a dummy, because the complete statement is a bit long and wasn't the issue. 
Thanks a lot for helping out and the clarification of your solution it really helps me a lot!